# Pinia: How to dynamically add new enteries to store state

Tags: vuejs3, nuxtjs3, pinia

I have a use case with the **pinia** in vue 3 that I want to dynamically add new entries to the pinia store using the store actions. for example if I have a state called **firstName** and if I call a the action of the store it should add new state called **lastName** in the state as well. Here is what I have tried

```js
import { defineStore } from "pinia";

export const useAdvanceListingsFilterStore = defineStore(
  "advance-listing-filters",
  {
    state: () => {
      return {
        firstName: "jhon",
      };
    },
    actions: {
      setLastName(payload) {
        return {
          ...this.state,
          lastName: payload,
        };
      },
     
     
    },
  }
);
```

The new state should include the **fistName** and **lastName** fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***UPDATE***

Accessing user over `$state` was not necessary. It works well directly:

```
this.user.lastName = payload;
```

```js
const { ref, createApp } = VueDemi
const { createPinia, defineStore, storeToRefs } = Pinia

const useAlertsStore = defineStore("advance-listing-filters",
  {
    state: () => ({ user: { firstName: "John" }}),
    actions: {
      setLastName(payload) {
        this.user.lastName = payload;
      }
    }
  }
)

const App = {
  setup() {
    const store = useAlertsStore()
    const { user } = storeToRefs(store)  
    const lastName = ref('Doe')
  return {
      store,
      user,
      lastName
    }
  }
}

const app = createApp(App)
const pinia = createPinia()
app.use(pinia)
app.mount('#app')
```

```css
[v-cloak] {  display: none; }
```

```html
<div id="app" v-cloak>
  <label>Name: </label> <b>{{store.user.firstName}} {{store.user.lastName}}</b><br /><br />
  <label>First Name:</label> <input :value="user.firstName" disabled /><br /><br />
  <label>Last Name:</label> <input v-model="lastName" /><br /><br />
  <button @click="store.setLastName(lastName)">Set Last Name</button>&nbsp;
  <button @click="store.$reset()">Reset</button>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-demi@0.13.11/lib/index.iife.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/pinia@2.0.30/dist/pinia.iife.js"></script>
```

---

The simplest way would by add `lastName: null` to your state, but I guess it is not what you are trying to achieve.

I have tried to add new items to the state internally using `state.$path` (see [Mutating the state](https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/state.html#mutating-the-state)), but the new `lastName` item was still not accessible outside the state using `state.lastName`. So I haven't found a way to achieve your goal directly. But there is another way to do it.

You can use a nested object to achieve your goal.

See the playground below.

I should also state, that adding state items dynamically makes your application  less predictable.
So, I would rather rethink the design and flow of data.

```js
const { ref, createApp, defineComponent } = Vue
const { createPinia, defineStore, storeToRefs } = Pinia

const useAlertsStore = defineStore("advance-listing-filters",
  {
    state: () => {
      return {
        user: { firstName: "John" }
      };
    },
    actions: {
      setLastName(payload) {
        this.$state.user.lastName = payload;
      }
    }
  }
)

const App = {
  setup() {
    const store = useAlertsStore()
    const { user } = storeToRefs(store)  
    const lastName = ref('Doe')
  return {
      store,
      user,
      lastName
    }
  }
}

const app = createApp(App)
const pinia = createPinia()
app.use(pinia)
app.mount('#app')
```

```html
<div id="app">
<label>Name: </label> <b>{{store.user.firstName}} {{store.user.lastName}}</b><br /><br />
<label>First Name:</label> <input :value="user.firstName" disabled /><br /><br />
<label>Last Name:</label> <input v-model="lastName" /><br /><br />
<button @click="store.setLastName(lastName)">Set Last Name</button>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-demi@0.13.11/lib/index.iife.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/pinia@2.0.30/dist/pinia.iife.js"></script>
```

Comment: Props for advising against using a dangerous pattern.

Comment: @tao it is not really clear what do you mean. Could you please clarify?

Comment: [*Props*](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/props) in plain English means *"proper respect or recognition"*. A.k.a: *"Well done"* / *"Good job"* / *"Thumbs up"*...

Comment: I thought you mean Vue's `props` and about broke my head trying to understand it ... ;-D   Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: I figured, once you asked what it meant. Couldn't help myself smiling. Although I'm using both meanings on a regular basis, I never connected them until you asked the question. :)

Comment: Please don't ever use the English slang word "Props" in the context of Vue, lol.